# Django: Relations between users (store unique pairs / combinations)

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to model the relations between users. For example: do they know each-other ?

Here is my first guess:

```
class Relation(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='related_a')
    b = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='related_b')
    met = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('a', 'b')
```

Obviously, this model allows `a == b`, and to have two `Relation` instances for the same two people.

To solve that, I tried to add stuff in the `save()` method and in a `ModelForm` to check `a.id < b.id`, so that I can only get one `Relation` for 2 given people, but it is not intuitive to use (we have to guess the good order when we want to add a `Relation`)

Is there any better way to store a unique pair (combinations) in Django models ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to extend User model to add field say `knownuser = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', blank=True)`

Comment: If there was only one (or a few) `models.BooleanField`, this would be the right thing to do ; but in my application, there are also `models.IntegerField`, and even  `models.DateField` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick fix I would use a m2m_changed pre_add signal handler that "puts a and b in the right order".

For "the right" solution I would use "Symmetrical Relationships - the Facebook model" part from the http://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/ blog.

If you can not afford this duplication performance wise, you should get creative with managers and it would be hairy.

Comment: Yes, I think the "symmetrical relationships" (ie. duplicating a-b and b-a relations) is a good answer for my use case, thank you !

And thanks for the blog link, btw, it seems pretty good :)

Answer (score 0):

For reference, `ManyToManyField` now have a [`symmetrical`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) option.